# generic lists accept integers and strings

Tags: java

Is there any kind of generic lists that accept integers and strings inputs?
thanks

Comment: What do you need over and above what `java.util.ArrayList`, `java.util.LinkedList` etc provide?

Comment: I mean like this :  `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` But I want to use keyboard to enter strings too

Comment: Well, then it's just a list of their common supertype: `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Ok ,, so Object is something stores numbers and words ..thank you brother :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a common ancestor in order to do that. In your case the only common ancestor is `Object` itself:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: `Object` is the common ancestor of all objects in java.

Comment: Is Object is implemented in java in my case ?

Comment: All classes in Java extend Object. That is where common methods like ``equals(...)``, ``hashCode()`` or ``toString()`` are defined. You can actually add anything in a ``List<Object>``.